# Azure OpenAI: Unable to deploy new model, the deploy button is in an unclickable state

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-openai

Unable to deploy new model, the deploy button is in an unclickable state, but I am the service owner and truely have full permissions.

[image: image: deploy button is disabled]

and from the 'view my access' page we can find that my account is the service owner with cognitive services related accesses:

[image: image: Resource Group IAM - view my access]

In addition, the account I am currently logged in with is also the owner of this Azure tenant and subscription, so theoretically I should have all the permissions for the platform. Did I configure something wrong?

I added the Cognitive Services OpenAI Contributor Role to my user group in the resource group IAM, but I still cannot deploy a new model.

Comment: I got the same behavior last month, I added 'Cognitive Services OpenAI Contributor' role like you did and did not have direct result. but after a few time it was fine - not sure if it was because I correctly fully disconnected / reconnected, or if it was related to something else...

Comment: I guess there might be some delay issues with the permission data synchronization of Azure. I tried logging out of my azure account and then logging back in, and the problem was solved. @NicolasR